# Старая Delphi 7. Работа с рестром windows. Как узнать удалось ли получить доступ к ключу HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE?

Tags: delphi-7, реестр

Нашёл в интернете по ссылке http://blog.ivru.net/?id=203 довольно не плохой пример по работе с реестром windows из старой версии Delphi.

Там же на писано, что для начала работы с реестром windows нужно определить основную ветку Reg.RootKey:= HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE; затем выбрать ключ раздела, например Reg.OpenKey('SOFTWARE',false); и уже после этого работать с параметрами то есть писать или читать значения параметров.

В той же статье я нашёл информацию, что существует разница при работе под админом и под обычным пользователем. А именно если я проделаю указанные выше действия(то есть присвою RootKey и затем выполню openKey) в программе открытой в Windows 10 под админом, то значения будут писаться по адресу HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\название_параметра=значение, а под обычным пользователем по адресу HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\название_параметра=значение

Дело в том что разрабатываемая программа иногда должна иметь возможность писать в раздел откуда информацию смогут считать все пользователи, то есть в HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE я понимаю что для проверки возможности записи в этот основной раздел я могу проверить наличие у приложения прав администратора. При этом такой вариант мне кажется не самый изящный по коду, полагаю что у объекта Reg есть и собственный функционал для этого просто я не нашёл его видимо.

Я думал что если у меня нет прав администратора, то значение свойства RootKey не будет присвоено и попробовал написать проверку if Key.RootKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE then но оказалось что значение присвоилось даже без наличия прав администратора у программы. И поскольку это строчка является установкой значения свойства и не возвращает результата то получается в ней не проверить.

Я конечно пока сделаю проверку прав админа, а если нужно писать в ключи для которых нужны права администратора, то предложу пользователю перезапустить программу с соответствующими правами, при этом далее возможно когда предстоит иметь дело с службами, возможно там такой функционал и при других правах может работать. Поэтому хотелось бы понять какие возможности у Reg есть чтобы я понимал в какой основной раздел реестра будет происходить запись. И если кто сталкивался, опишите какие подводные камни работы с реестром Windows из Delphi могут быть под админом и без него, а так же при работе приложения в качестве службы.